# How to create a RSA public key from a unsigned char * modulus and exponent 65537(RSA_F4)

Tags: c++, c, linux, openssl

I'm trying generate a rsa public key from a modulus type char[], and I now the exponent is RSA_F4(65537);
But when I'm trying generate my public key using this values for "n" and "e", the RSA_public_encrypt, return -1;

Thanks!

My code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rc4.h>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{

//modulus in format char hex;
char key[] = "C0E7FC730EB5CF85B040EC25DAEF288912641889AD651B3707CFED9FC5A1D3F6C40062AD46E3B3C3E21D4E71CC4800C80226D453242AEB2F86D748B41DDF35FD";

    char palavra[] = "teste";
    char crip[512];
    int ret;
    RSA * pubkey = RSA_new();
    BIGNUM * modul = BN_new();
    BIGNUM * expon = BN_new();

    BN_hex2bn(&modul, (const char *) key);
    BN_hex2bn(&expon, "010001");

    cout << "N KEY: " << BN_bn2hex(modul) << endl;
    cout << "E KEY: " << BN_bn2hex(expon) << endl;

    pubkey->n = modul;
    pubkey->e = expon;

    cout << "N PUB KEY: " << BN_bn2hex(pubkey->n) << endl;
    cout << "E PUB KEY: " << BN_bn2hex(pubkey->e) << endl;

    if (RSA_public_encrypt(strlen((const char *) palavra), (const unsigned char *) palavra, (unsigned char *) crip, pubkey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING ))
    {
        printf("ERRO encrypt\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SUC encrypt\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear to read your modulus into `x`, which you never declare, leaving `modul` as 0.  You also never put the modulus into `pubkey`, so its probably still blank, giving you an error when you try to call `RSA_public_encrypt`.   If you want actual help, you need to post the real code that you've tried to compile and run.

Comment: Sorry but my last post was inserted for a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something that looks more like:

```
RSA *pubkey = RSA_new();
int len = BN_hex2bn(&pubkey->n, (const char *)p);
if (len == 0 || p[len])
    fprintf(stderr, "'%s' does not appear to be a valid modulus\n", p);
BN_hex2bn(&pubkey->e, "010001");
```

**edit**

Your code works fine, except for the error check.  RSA_public_encrypt returns the size of the ciphertext on success, not 0, so to make the code above work, add a `<= 0` test to `if` line:

```
if (RSA_public_encrypt(....) <= 0)
```

Comment: Sorry but my last post was inserted for a mistake. Now my ask is complete, can you save me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is some C code, that does the trick:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

// cheating, .. ignoring deprecation warnings
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

unsigned char *base64_decode(const char* base64data, int* len) {
   BIO *b64, *bmem;
   size_t length = strlen(base64data);
   unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(length);
   b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
   BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
   bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)base64data, length);
   bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
   *len = BIO_read(bmem, buffer, length);
   BIO_free_all(bmem);
   return buffer;
}

BIGNUM* bignum_base64_decode(const char* base64bignum) {
   BIGNUM* bn = NULL;
   int len;
   unsigned char* data = base64_decode(base64bignum, &len);
   if (len) {
       bn = BN_bin2bn(data, len, NULL);
   }
   free(data);
   return bn;
}

EVP_PKEY* RSA_fromBase64(const char* modulus_b64, const char* exp_b64) {
   BIGNUM *n = bignum_base64_decode(modulus_b64);
   BIGNUM *e = bignum_base64_decode(exp_b64);

   if (!n) printf("Invalid encoding for modulus\n");
   if (!e) printf("Invalid encoding for public exponent\n");

   if (e && n) {
       EVP_PKEY* pRsaKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
       RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
       rsa->e = e;
       rsa->n = n;
       EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pRsaKey, rsa);
       return pRsaKey;
   } else {
       if (n) BN_free(n);
       if (e) BN_free(e);
       return NULL;
   }
}

void assert_syntax(int argc, char** argv) {
   if (argc != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Description: %s takes a RSA public key modulus and exponent in base64 encoding and produces a public key file in PEM format.\n", argv[0]);
      fprintf(stderr, "syntax: %s <modulus_base64> <exp_base64> <output_file>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   assert_syntax(argc, argv);

   const char* modulus = argv[1];
   const char* exp = argv[2];
   const char* filename = argv[3];

   EVP_PKEY* pkey = RSA_fromBase64(modulus, exp);

   if (pkey == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "an error occurred :(\n");
      return 2;
    } else {
       printf("success decoded into RSA public key\n");
       FILE* file = fopen(filename, "w");
       PEM_write_PUBKEY(file, pkey);
       fflush(file);
       fclose(file);
       printf("written to file: %s\n", filename);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See this link for further info: http://www.techper.net/2012/06/01/converting-rsa-public-key-modulus-and-exponent-into-pem-file/

Comment: Hi I am able to write public pem but getting blank private key. here is my code - char szModulus = "1162" ; char *szExp = "827655" ; RSA rsa1 = RSA_new(); int ret = BN_hex2bn(&rsa1->n,szModulus) ; ret = BN_hex2bn(&rsa1->d,szExp) ; FILE *fp; fp = fopen("/Users/ysi/Desktop/privateKey.pem", "wb"); .Please help me. Thank you